# How to set key in queryParams?

Tags: angular

How can i add key as value from service ?

```
menu.keyword
```

is varible that i get from api but and have value. i want to pass that value to be in queryParams in url as key. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Right now in url i get `menu.keyword = 22` and i dont want that i want `processId=22` because `menu.keyword` have value `processId`.

I know in ts that i can add something : `{[menu.keyword]:menu.refParamter3}` how can i in html?

Comment: So you get `menu.keyword` back from one service and you want to pass it as `?processId=22` (query string) to another service?

Comment: no i want to add it in queryParms. menu.keyword returns string word processId and i want that be a key in queryParams. refParamters return 22, so i want to have queryParams:{menu.keyword:refParamter} and i will get processId=22 in url if i merge those two.

Comment: Oh, I see. So is `{ [menu.keyword]: menu.refParameter3 }` not working?

Comment: its not working in html. I get this :  Unexpected token [, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 3 in [{ [menu.keyword]: menu.refParameter3 }]

Answer (score 0):

after getting your queryParams:

```
Object.keys(queryParams).forEach(key => { 
// you can delete a query params
// you can change key ...
});
```

in the ned you can navigate to routes with the new queryParams

```
this.router.navigate(['myRoute'], {queryParams})
```